# A problem on Relay Power loss

Tags: power, relay, switching, loss

On our quadcopter, we're carrying a switching circuit that would allow the switching between two batteries. When using the 2 Channel Relay Module, the quadcopter is having a hard time flying with it. When directing the battery to the quadcopter, the quadcopter doeesn't have a hard time with flight. Is there such a big power loss from such a small relay? Are there any other options? or is there a solution?

The reason for switching the circuit is because one battery will be used by the quadcopter, the other one will be charging. So after the first battery is drained, the other battery will then be used for the quadcopter, the other one will charge. So on and so forth.

This is the relay used by our thesis.

http://www.sainsmart.com/sainsmart-2-channel-5v-relay-module-for-arduino-raspberry-pi.html

Comment: Why not just put the batteries in parallel and use them both? What's the purpose of switching?

Comment: Can you add details about the swap battery procedure? Are you just trying to retain settings when swapping batteries? I'm guessing you land, stop the motors, swap batteries but want to not have to reboot the quadcopter during the swap? I have an idea but need to know your swap process.

Comment: We have a thesis that involves solar recharging. So the idea is that the first battery would be used by the quad, the second one will be charging, if the first battery is drained, the second battery is used by the quad and the first battery is charged. So on and so forth

Comment: Please use a relay with a less VA , if possible may I know the relay VA and your circuit current consumption?

Comment: Sorry I was not able to put that in @Nick

Comment: The relay takes 10 A continuously. Let's assume at 1 W loss. That's 10 mohm. How much does your quadcopter draw, 50 A? That's half a volt drop. What's the battery voltage?

Comment: Less VA has nothing to do with it. He suffers from contact resistance.

Comment: Wait what? On board the quad? What do you expect to gain from this?

Comment: @winny So wait the quadcopter suffers from a current limiter? It's a 11.1V 3s battery.

Comment: It's not a current limiter per say, but even a 500 mV drop, assuming 50 A draw, is far from negligible. How much current does the quad consume?

Comment: @winny It consumes about around that number. 40A-50A. I don't follow the explanation I'm sorry.

Comment: You are dropping half a volt or more over your relay. Possibly more if you didn't interface it well. This is significant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42700/discussion-between-henry-lachica-and-winny).

Comment: From the product page: _Equiped [sic] with high-current relay, AC250V 10A ; DC30V 10A_ - Those specs will be optimistic on a good day, and you thought pushing 50A through it would be ok? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are relays that will do what you want, these are not the ones.
Better would be either a suitable low Rdson MOSFET per battery, or a properly rated relay.

Relays of this type can generally be expected to be junk for practical purposes at LV DC and dangerous junk at mains voltages. See the pinout footprint in the datasheet below - isolation is much reduced by placing the common contact between the coil contacts. OKish on LV, terrible for mains.

You need to say what Voltage and MAX current you are switching.
The relay is dated at 28V DC at:
10A in SPST mode with resistive load.
7A in SPDT mode with resistive load.
5A in SPST mode with inductive load.
3A in SPDT mode with inductive load.

What current MAXIMUM does your copter draw?
What is your operating voltage?
What voltage drop do you measure across the relay contacts during operation?
[**If** you have not measured it, why are you asking questions about it?]

At 10A the contacts MAY drop 1V.
At 50A = 5V !!! :-( (and the relay would die)

While the 100 milliOhm contact resistance specification (see below) is a 
.

I found [**this data sheet**](http://www.datasheetbay.com/pdf/720556/SRD-05VDC-SL-C.html) - the same in details as Edsign links to but not as nicely presented.

The contact resistance is shown as "not more than 100 milliOhm" - Agh !!!!!!!!!!!!!!
At 10A that would drop 1V at maximum allowed resistance.
At 50 A = 5V drop.

---

Added:

OP advises.
Ioperating ~= 50A
Battery = 3S LiIon.
Vbattery = 3.6V x 3 = 10.8V nominal. (  9V min, 12.6V max)

The chosen relay is totally unsuited to the task.  You either need

- A  50A relay. This is not hard to achieve at your voltage but somewhat power hungry. A car horn relay may work depending on operate period allowed. 
  OR
- A low Rdson MOSFET per battery.

A MOSFET at 50A will dissipate
I^2 x R = 2.5 Watt per milliOhm of Rdson.
So even a 5 mOhm FET dissipates 12.5+ Watts - not undoable but almost makes a properly rated relay attractive. (But, see below, a 0.4 milliOhm Rdson MOSFET -  1 Watt at 50 A.

You can buy 30V, 300A, 0.4 milliOhm Rdson MOSFEts for $US3.43 each i nquantity 10 (!!!). [**Infineon IPT004N03L**](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/IPT004N03L_rev1.2.pdf?folderId=db3a304313b8b5a60113cee8763b02d7&fileId=db3a30433e9d5d11013e9e0f382600c2). Utterly awesome. Interesting package . 8 power SFN - looks unusual but has drain tab on 1 side, 8 pins on other. Pin 1 = gate, 2-8 = source.

Good [starting search here](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/transistors-fets-mosfets-single/1376381)

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty awesome mosfet, it can even function usefully at logic voltage levels :)

Comment: Hi I'm sorry for my late reply @RussellMcMahon . Thank you for this very detailed explanation. I've already gone on experimenting MOSFETS too. All my setups failed to actually pass on the right current to the quadcopter. I fail to see why. This is the current MOSFET we're using. http://datasheetz.com/data/Discrete%20Semiconductor%20Products/MOSFETs%20-%20Single/PHU78NQ03LT-datasheetz.html The MOSFET switches right like what I want it to. The problem with it, the quadcopter does not even fly when connected to this MOSFET.

Comment: @HenryLachica it would be a **really** good idea to see the circuit you are using - even if it SEEMS trivial. And what voltage are you using on the FET gate? That FET should achieve about 0.5V drop at 50A IF turned hard on. As it's an N channel FET it **MUST** go in the NEGATIVE lead to the motor / controller if Vgate is not above V+. . Source = battery negative. DRAIN to motor controller. Gate is switched to +V to turn on. There are ways to allow it to be in the +ve  motor lead but then the gate needs to be switched to ABOVE V+ motor by 5 to 10 V.

Comment: Better versions of datasheet [here](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PHD78NQ03LT.pdf) and [here](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/NXP%20PDFs/PHU78NQ03LT.pdf)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon The gate of the FET comes from the arduino as it controls the switching of the gate. The Vgs has 5.2V. The Drain of the FET comes from the negative of the quadcopter, the source of the FET goes to  common ground of the battery, arduino, and the quadcopter.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Yep seems like I did right from you just explained. From the datasheets, does the MOSFET needs a bigger input for its Vgs?

Comment: You need 10V on the gate of that FET. What is your battery voltage? What gate voltage are you driving the FET with? See [fig5 here](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PHD78NQ03LT.pdf) - at Vgs = 4V you never get to 50A at 1V drop Vds. At 10V Vgs you get ~= 0.4V across FET at 25C but it will be higher when FET heats up. At 50A dissipation in FET at 0.5V is 25W !!!!!!

Comment: (1) What is the battery voltage ? (2) What is the battery voltage ? (3) What is the battery voltage ? (4) What is .... :-) ?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I'm really sorry .The battery voltage is 12.6V max, 11.1V min. The input of the Vgs comes from the arduino which is at 5.2V only.

Comment: I see I said 3S LiIon above but do not know where I saw that. See fig5 again. See Vgs = 5V curve. At 50A Vds = 0.6V. Now see fig 10. When hot Rdson about 50% higher so FET drop about 0.9V TYPICAL. 50A x 0.9V = 45 Watts !!!!

Comment: @RussellMcMahon How do I interpret that, does that mean it cannot support that much amperes going through the MOSFET?

Comment: Oh good. 12.6V max = 3S LiIon. 9V when flat, 10.8V typical, 12.6V max. The FEt is not really good enough but will work better if you drive it with 10V or more. Max Vgs = 20V. As a test connect gate to V+ (12V) via a say 1k resistor. (remove Arduino drive first. That will show you what power you can get AND FET will try and melt. Page 4 datasheet says thermal resistance is 1.4 C rose per Watt - so at 40W rise = 56C. At ambient of 30C say FET body = 86C with a perfect heatsink. You DO NOT want to have to airlift perfect heatsinks! :-) You need a better FET. Try as above just to see.

Comment: Pore over datasheet - pli\ug in figures you have to the available graphs and see the implications. But, the FET is not good enough. In my answer I noted that at 50 A you get 2.5W dissipation in FET  **PER MILLIOHM** of Rdson. And real Rdson will usually be 50% or so higher than datasheet value when FET is hot. So a 9 milliOhm FET = sat 13 mO actual x 2.5W/mO =~  30 Watts. You would need a 2 /W heatsink or larger [**Like this one**](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/heatsinks/0271842/) or [this one](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/heatsinks/0158562/)
A 1 or 2 milliOhm FET or better is really needed

Comment: Or a properly specified relay.